# Completion Suggester Foreign Language Accents Greek

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, analyzer

I am trying to use the Completion suggester with Greek language. Unfortunately I have problems with accents like `ά`. I've tried a few ways.

One was simply to set the greek analyzer in the mapping the other a lowercase analyzer with asciifolding. No success, with greek analyser I dont even get a result with the accent.

Below is what I did, would be great if anyone can help me out here.

### Mapping

```
PUT t1
{
  "mappings": {
    "profession" : {
      "properties" : {
        "text" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "suggest" : {
            "type" : "completion",
            "analyzer": "greek"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Dummy

```
POST t1/profession/?refresh
{
    "suggest" : {
        "input": [ "Μάγειρας"]
    }
    ,"text": "Μάγειρας"
}
```

### Query

```
GET t1/profession/_search
{ "suggest": 
  { "profession" : 
      { "prefix" : "Μα"
      , "completion" : 
        { "field" : "suggest"}
      }}}
```

Comment: What happens if you use the prefix with the accent?

Comment: @aclokay 
When I use Greek language analyser I don't get anything. With lowercase and asciifolding i get  at lest a result with accent, but not without.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it with a custom analyzer or via a plugin for es which i highly recommend when it comes to non-latin texts.

### Option 1

```
PUT t1
{ "settings": 
    { "analysis": 
      { "filter": 
        { "greek_lowercase": 
          { "type":       "lowercase"
          , "language":   "greek"
          }  
        }
      , "analyzer": 
          { "autocomplete": 
            { "tokenizer": "lowercase"
            , "filter": 
                [ "greek_lowercase" ]
          }
        }
    }}
, "mappings": {
    "profession" : {
      "properties" : {
        "text" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "suggest" : {
            "type" : "completion",
            "analyzer": "autocomplete"
        }
      }}}
}
```

### Option 2 ICU Plugin

Install ES Plugin:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-icu.html

```
{ "settings": {
"index": {
    "analysis": {
    "normalizer": {
        "latin": {
        "filter": [
            "custom_latin_transform"
        ]
        }
    },
    "analyzer": {
        "latin": {
        "tokenizer": "keyword",
        "filter": [
            "custom_latin_transform"
        ]
        }
    },
    "filter": {
        "noDelimiter": {"type": "word_delimiter"},
        "custom_latin_transform": {
        "type": "icu_transform",
        "id": "Greek-Latin/UNGEGN; Lower(); NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC"
        }
    }
    }
}
}
, "mappings":
{ "doc" : {
"properties" : {
    "verbose" : {
        "type" : "keyword"
    },
    "name" : {
        "type" : "keyword"
    },
    "slugHash":{
        "type" : "keyword",
        "normalizer": "latin"
    },
    "level": { "type": "keyword" },
    "hirarchy": {
        "type" : "keyword"
        },
    "geopoint": { "type": "geo_point"  },
    "suggest" :
        { "type" : "completion"
        , "analyzer": "latin"
        , "contexts":
        [ { "name": "level"
            , "type": "category"
            , "path": "level"
            }
        ]
        }}

    }

}}
```